# how to print this data in table format using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am able to show the data returned from the ajax call as an alert, however I would like to show it in a table format using `ejs`.

Can someone help?

**AJAX Call**

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/render',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        alert(data[i].item);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label style="margin-left: 20px;">Shopping item</label>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
      <label>Quantity</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input type="text" id="item" name="item" />&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
      <input type="text" id="quan" name="quan" />&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add item" style="background-color: #a3a3c2; color:white; width:170px;" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$('#submit').on('click',function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/render',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

           for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
           {
             var Html="<tr>
                <td>"+data[i].item+"</td>
                <td>"+data[i].Quantity+"</td>
            </tr>";
            $('#tbody').append(Html);

           }
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Answer is good, but where is the "show it in a table format using ejs" part? I mean the question was quite misleading , if this is the correct answer! Am I whining ... yeah a little bit  ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve.
But if you want to use ejs, then you should create an [ejs](http://ejs.co/) template where you can pass the data.

Get your data and call the template with it;

```
$('#submit').on('click',function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.json',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

           var result = new EJS({url: 'productstemplate.ejs'}).render({products:data}); 
           document.getElementById('product_list').innerHTML = result
        }
        });
    });
```

I made a working sample of an ajax request, that uses an ejs to render in this
[plunkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/2cOFrI4gBEEtytCovFLP?p=preview), maybe this helps you out